# How to move UsedRange into Array for processing tasks and then copy back to the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Regarding this question “combine or merge cells with the same values vertically and horizontally” [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69105746/how-to-combine-or-merge-cells-with-the-same-values-vertically-and-horizontally),
the provided answer (edited one) it works ,but with big range (e.g. 30 thousands rows) the macro takes a very long time to finish (no error raised but excel is not responding). 
so, instead of putting only the first column on array, 
**Is it possible** to move all the `usedRange` into array and processing all the tasks on memory and then copy back to the sheet? 
I do not care about any lost format at all (fonts, rows height,..). 
In advance, grateful for your helps.

```
Sub DeleteSimilarRows_AppendLastColuns()
    Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet, arrWork, rngDel As Range, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim strVal As String, m As Long, boolNoFilter As Boolean
 
    Set ws = ActiveSheet: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
    arrWork = ws.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value2 'Place the range in an array to make iteration faster
 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrWork) - 1                'Iterate between the array elements:
        If arrWork(i, 1) = arrWork(i + 1, 1) Then
            'Determine how many consecutive similar rows exist:__________________
            For k = 1 To LastRow
                If i + k + 1 >= UBound(arrWork) Then Exit For
                If arrWork(i, 1) <> arrWork(i + k + 1, 1) Then Exit For
            Next k '___________________________________________
 
            For j = 14 To 14                  'Build the concatenated string of cells in range "N":
                strVal = ws.Cells(i, j).Value
                For m = 1 To k
                    strVal = strVal & vbLf & ws.Cells(i + m, j).Value
                Next m
                ws.Cells(i, j).Value = strVal: strVal = ""
           Next j
 
           For m = 1 To k                    'Place the cells for rows to be deleted in a Union range, to delete at the end, at once
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                     Set rngDel = ws.Range("A" & i + m)
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, ws.Range("A" & i + m))
                End If
         Next m
         i = i + k: If i >= UBound(arrWork) - 1 Then Exit For 'Increment the i variable and exiting if the resulted value exits the array size
       End If
    Next i
 
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete    'Delete the not necessary rows
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only possible, but preferable. The speed increase is insane. This is how I do it:

Data from the spread sheet gets saved into a variable from type Variant -- the result is a 2-dimensional array (even if there is only one row/column in the range).

```vb
' Read data into Array
Dim data as Variant ' Important: has to be type Variant. 
Set data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2 ' .Value or .Value2, as needed
```

When saving data back into the sheet, this code automatically selects a range of the appropriate size.

```vb
' Write array into cells
Dim target as Range
Set target = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1) ' Start at A1 / R1C1; Change as appropriate
target.Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
```

Comment: Your answer has a minor error. `(even if there is only one row/column/cell in the range)`. If the range is just ONE cell, assignment to a variant results in a scalar value and not a 2D array.

Comment: You are correct - my mistake. I did correct it.