# Copy values from previous rows (with same ID) to the blank cells on the last row (with the same ID)

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

As you see on the above picture, I have three rows with the same ID value `”1”` . 
`Rows(“5:5”)` is the last row which has ID value `”1”` and it has two blank cells (`E5:F5`),  
I need to fill these blank cells with corresponding value from the previous nearest row which has the same ID value `”1”`, 
If the previous corresponding value is also blank then seek for it in the before previous row (same ID value) and so on. 
`Rows(“6:6”)` is the only row with ID value `”2”`, so it will be kept as it is (even if it has blank values). 
I could not find a direct way to fulfil my task and I have used the below long workarounds: 
1- Insert a helper column and filled with serial number from 1 to lastRow on the sheet. 
2- Sort column(A) xlAscending and the helper column `xlDescending`: 
3- then `Merge` corresponding cells on the rows which have the same ID value. 
4- `UnMerge` all the rows on the sheet. 
5- use another macro to delete the blank rows. 
6- at last delete the helper column. 
The issue with these steps that it is time consuming and I am fear it may lead to hang excel application, 
**Note**: in my actual dataset,the header is the first two rows.
In advance, great thanks for your help.

```
Sub Inser_Column_and_Add_SerialNumber()
   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Dim LastRow As Long, Count As Long, arr, arrA, i As Long
   LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Count = 1
    arr = ws.Range("A3:A" & LastRow).Value
    arrA = ws.Range("A3:A" & LastRow).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) <> "" Then arrA(i, 1) = Count:  Count = Count + 1
    Next i
    ws.Range("B3").Resize(UBound(arrA), 1).Value = arrA
End Sub
```

This is the code of `Merge` corresponding cells on the rows which have the same ID value:

```
Sub Merge_corresponding_Cell_on_Similar_Rows()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
       ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData        'Clear any Filter
    Else
       ws.Rows("2:2").AutoFilter
    End If
       
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear            'Clear any previous sorting

    ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ws.AutoFilter.Sort.Apply

    Dim LastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, arrWork, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     
    arrWork = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value2
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrWork) - 1
    
        If arrWork(i, 1) = arrWork(i + 1, 1) Then        'Determine how many consecutive similar rows exist
                                            
            For k = 1 To LastRow
                If i + k + 1 >= UBound(arrWork) Then Exit For
                If arrWork(i, 1) <> arrWork(i + k + 1, 1) Then Exit For
            Next k
            
            For j = 1 To lastCol
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, j), ws.Cells(i + k, j)).Merge 'merge all the necessary cells based on previously determined k
           Next j
           
       End If
       
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

| **ID** | **Name** | **Name** | **Country** | **Town** | **Street** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |  |  | D1 |  |
| 1 | 11 | AA |  |  | E1 |
| 3 | 31 | 3b | 3c |  | 3e |
| **1** | **12** | **BB** | **CC** |  |  |
| 2 | AV | FF | ERT | 2b | 2b |
| **3** | **33** |  | **3ccc** |  | **333** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily in Power Query, available in Excel 2010+ and `365`

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next lines to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table43"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"WO", type any}, {"Name", type text}, {"Country", type text}, {"Town", type text}, {"Street", type any}}),

//Group by ID
// Then fill down to fill in the blanks and return the last row of the table
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"sll", 
        each  Table.FromRecords({Table.Last(Table.FillDown(_, Table.ColumnNames(_)))}), 
        type table [ID=nullable number, WO=any, Name=nullable text, Country=nullable text, Town=nullable text, Street=any]}}),

//Remove ID column
//then expand the grouped table
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"ID"}),
    #"Expanded sll" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "sll", {"ID", "WO", "Name", "Country", "Town", "Street"}),

//Sort to desired order
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded sll",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works correctly with my provided sample , I will adapt for my actual dataset and feed you back.

Comment: I tried with my actual dataset and It works as it should , it is an additional option beside vba. Please, Did you used a wizard in excel to generate this code ?

Comment: @Leedo Some of the code was generated from the Power Query UI. But the custom aggregation in the Table.Group function was not. Neither were the comments nor some of the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This code now place the result from column K.

```
Sub fill_last()
Dim searchrange As Range, found As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Merge")   'set to the actual sheet name
lastcol = 6                                            'set the last column's count of the table
ReDim finalrow(1 To 1, 1 To lastcol)    'this collects for a unique item in column A  the last non-empty value of each column
lastrow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row   'get the last value in column A
Set searchrange = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

'this section filters in place the table based on unique values of column A, and save them in - uniques - array.

searchrange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, , , True
filtered_lastrow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
uniquecount = searchrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
ReDim uniques(1 To uniquecount)
ReDim resultbuffer(1 To uniquecount, 1 To lastcol)
pointer = 1
For i = 2 To lastrow
  If Rows(i).Hidden = False Then uniques(pointer) = Cells(i, 1): pointer = pointer + 1
Next i
sh.ShowAllData

'this section iterates on every unique column A values, define the last value for every column for a specific unique value of column A

For i = 1 To uniquecount
  For j = 1 To lastcol
    finalrow(1, j) = Empty
  Next j
  Set found = searchrange.Find(uniques(i), Range("A1"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    Set foundaddr = found
  Do
    Set foundlast = found
    For j = 1 To lastcol
      If Not IsEmpty(found.EntireRow.Cells(j)) Then finalrow(1, j) = found.EntireRow.Cells(j)
    Next j
    Set found = searchrange.FindNext(found)
  Loop Until found.Address = foundaddr.Address
  actrow = foundlast.Row  'actrow stores the last row's number of a specific unique value of column A (only for testing.)
  For j = 1 To lastcol
    resultbuffer(i, j) = finalrow(1, j)    'resultbuffer collects the final rows for every unique values
  Next j
Next i

' create the result table

sh.Range("A1:F1").Copy sh.Range("K1:P1")  'copy the header row
sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, "K"), sh.Cells(uniquecount + 1, 10 + lastcol)) = resultbuffer  'set the result table to the actual values
'head = sh.Range("A1:F1")
'sh.Cells.Delete
'sh.Range("A1:F1") = head
'sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, "A"), sh.Cells(uniquecount + 1, 6)) = resultbuffer
End Sub
```

If you want to replace the original table with the result, then activate the last four comments line and comment out the previous two.

The result table is identical as in your question.

Comment: There are a lot of variables not declared, I got this error `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set` @ this line `If Not IsEmpty(found.EntireRow.Cells(j)) Then`

Comment: Variables are implicitly declared in VBA. In the line you mentioned found is declared with Set statement (5 lines before), finalrow array declared with ReDim statement (in 6th line). Do you have any value in column A?

Comment: Yes I have values in column A, But the first two cells are merged.

Comment: That not corresponds to your `Current` screenshot. Try with unmerged cells.

Comment: I tried with my actual dataset and It works as it should and more fast than mine, But Please can you optimize it by adding helpful comments and the correct variables declaration.

Comment: @Leedo pls. find the added descriptions of the functioning of the code

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next approach. The code uses a dictionary, filled with arrays of each ID occurrence, which to finally be processed and extract the empty elements of the last occurrence from precedents.

It returns in the same sheet, **starting from H:H column** (it can return anywhere...). The processed IDs will be returned as they have been found during the iteration. If you need IDs to be sorted, the last code  line may involve such an ascending sort. In fact, I will sort the dictionary (in memory) and adapt the code I intended to post:

```
Sub ProcessSameIDs()
  'The code needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'. It may work using Late binding...
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngH As Range, arr, arrIt, arrFin
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, k As Long, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rngH = sh.Range("A1:F2")   'the header (two merged rows...)
  arr = sh.Range("A3:A" & lastR).Value2
  
  'place in the dictionary the necessary data
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    With Application
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
            'place the correspondent 1D array as item (it could work with 2D, too, but it was easyer to check):
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), Array(.Transpose(.Transpose(sh.Range("A" & i + 2).Resize(, 6).Value2)))
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 1)) 'the array dictionary cannot be updated dirrectly!
            ReDim Preserve arrIt(UBound(arrIt) + 1)
            arrIt(UBound(arrIt)) = .Transpose(.Transpose(sh.Range("A" & i + 2).Resize(, 6).Value2))
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrIt 'place the updated array back in the dictionary item
        End If
    End With
  Next i
  
  'sort the dictionary keys:
  sortDictionary dict
  
  'process the dictionary items:
  k = 1
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To 6) 'redim the final array
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    'place the last item elements in the final array:
    For j = 1 To 6
        If dict.Items()(i)(UBound(dict.Items()(i)))(j) <> "" Then 'place in columns not empty elements:
            arrFin(k, j) = dict.Items()(i)(UBound(dict.Items()(i)))(j): 'Stop
        Else
            'fill the gaps with values of previous ID occurrences, if any:
            For m = UBound(dict.Items()(i)) - 1 To 0 Step -1 'iterate backwards between arrays to extract missing element:
                If dict.Items()(i)(m)(j) <> "" Then
                    arrFin(k, j) = dict.Items()(i)(m)(j): Exit For 'exiting when the non empty element has been found
                End If
            Next m
        End If
    Next j
    k = k + 1 'increment the array row variable
  Next i
  
  'copy the header:
  rngH.Copy sh.Range("H1")
  
  'drop the processed array content, at once:
  sh.Range("H3").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin
  
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Sub sortDictionary(d As Scripting.Dictionary) 'sorting the d dictionary
    Dim arrKeys, i As Long, j As Long, temp, dS As New Scripting.Dictionary
    arrKeys = d.keys
    'bubble sort the keys array:
    For i = LBound(arrKeys) To UBound(arrKeys) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(arrKeys)
            If arrKeys(i) > arrKeys(j) Then
                temp = arrKeys(i): arrKeys(i) = arrKeys(j)
                arrKeys(j) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrKeys)
        dS(arrKeys(i)) = d(arrKeys(i))
    Next i
    Set d = dS
End Sub
```

Comment: I am afraid to say it works correctly ,But it is slower than my answer. I just tried with a range of 1733 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I hope simple loops will be adequate in this case. I assumed that the ID was consecutive integers from 1.

```
Sub CopyReplace()
    Dim data, result
    data = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    Dim maxID As Long, ID
    ID = data
    ReDim Preserve ID(1 To UBound(data), 1 To 1)
    maxID = Application.Max(ID)
    ' result without header
    ReDim result(1 To maxID, 1 To UBound(data, 2))
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(data)
        k = data(i, 1) ' ID
        result(k, 1) = k
        For j = 2 To UBound(data, 2)
            If Len(data(i, j)) > 0 Then result(k, j) = data(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    ' print result
    Range("A2:F" & maxID + 1) = result
    Range("A" & maxID + 2 & ":F" & UBound(data)).Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: The **ID** is not consecutive integers from 1 , I just provided in my sample for the sake simplicity

Comment: The answer is based on the example. If you can't fit it yourself, then correct the example to one that matches your data.